# What is the best way to automatically sign in a firebase user after email has been verified?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

It's a fact that Firebase allows a user to sign in without the email verification process being finished but nevertheless I would like to allow in only those users that verified their emails. 
To be even more precise, I would like them to be redirected to the home page after they click the verification link.
Currently if I click the link I get forwarded to the page that shows the verification status (like email has been successfully verified) but then nothing happens. Currently the scenario a use has to follow is like this:

1) Click sign up.

2) Fill in the sign up form.

3) Click `Submit`.

4) Be redirected to the email verification page that basically says that you should check your email box and verify your email.

Potentially, in the controller of my `EmailVerificationComponent` component I can subscribe to AuthState and wait for a user object to be emitted, then when it's emitted I will update my firebase user and then when the actual user reloads any of the app pages currently opened he will be automatically logged in. But the problem here is that the user may close the page he should be redirected to after submitting the form, he may close the whole browser thing, he may forget why he was trying to sign up altogether etc. Another problem is that even if he doesn't close anything, he will have to reload the page in order to land on the home page.

Taking all that into consideration, I have the following question: What is the right way to log in a user after email verification? I think the best way would be to redirect him to the main page after the email is verified but from reading the official docs I still can't figure out how to do that...

Additional info:

I'm writing the clientside in Angular 8.

Comment: You should consider using [email link sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth). This matches your needs. You will only allow the user to sign in after the email is verified (link is clicked).